# I've vectorized a custom function, why is outer giving me an error?

Tags: r, vectorization

Take

```
  cubeAndAdd<-function(x,y){x^3+y^3}
  outer(-1:1,-1:1,function(x,y) Vectorize(cubeAndAdd(x,y)))
```

Upon running this, you will get the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In formals(fun) : argument is not a function
```

Why is this? After all, if I truly wasn't using a function, then this code wouldn't run at all.

Comment: Maybe just do: `outer(-1:1,-1:1,Vectorize(cubeAndAdd))`? Since you already define x and y, is there a need to redefine a lambda?

Comment: @NelsonGon That works and is definitely better than what I had, but it doesn't explain the error.

Comment: The error is defining `function(x,y)` again which introduces another lambda and hence it is unclear what to match to the function. If you really want to be explicit, then: `outer(-1:1,-1:1,Vectorize(function(x,y) cubeAndAdd(x,y)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from what you're 'feeding' to `Vectorize`.

`Vectorize` wants a function as its argument.  `cubeAndAdd` is a function, but `cubeAndAdd(x,y)` is a function *call*.

To make your `outer` loop syntactically correct, you should use `Vectorize` to create the vectorized function, and then call that new function:

```
outer(-1:1,-1:1,function(x,y) Vectorize(cubeAndAdd)(x,y))
```

Here, `Vectorize(cubeAndAdd)` is the function, and you're calling it using (x,y) as arguments: so `Vectorize(cubeAndAdd)(x,y)`

(Although the suggestion to just remove the entire anonymous `function(x,y)` from the `outer` loop works here (and makes the one-liner shorter), it's often a good idea to explicitly 'feed' the arguments to the function, as you are doing, since this allows one to use functions that expect additional arguments).